# Laravel collective action

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner at laravel. I want to use laravel collective (on laravel 9 version). And actually i want to use action. I write it in my blade:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and when i open it in browser it gives me error Action PostsController@store not defined.
i do not know. help me. i try to googled it but did not find. also i tried [PostsController::class] but not worked. i tried everything what i know

Comment: I think for action, you should use route() function.

Comment: To use PostsController@store, you need to define namespace in I think RouteServiceProvider.

Comment: and how? please write

Comment: I never used Form::open() let me have a look.

Comment: Try providing the full namespace: `App\Http\Controllers\PostController@store`. Better still, use a `named route`.

Comment: ```<form method="post" action="{{ route(routeName)}}"></form>```
You can define ```named routes``` in your web.php file.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this, I think you should focus on reading docs. If That's a bit difficult, then watch some sort of series. Better watch *Laravel 8 from Scratch* on laracasts.

Comment: For CRUD people mostly use Route::resource("/posts", PostsController::class); This automatically creates a few routes for you.

Answer (score 1):

### Best Solution - Using named routes

From documentation of [Laravel Collectives](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html#opening-a-form) you may come to know that you can use named routes in your code. So, we better use named route.

```php
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'route.name', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

### Alternatives

You could either string including the namespace of controller with it to work

```php
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

or you could modify your RouteServiceProvider file and change the controller namespace there. `protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';` this approach allows you to use `'ControllerName@method'` controllers created in App\Http\Controllers directory.

Comment: OP wants to use the [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/) package which your answer (whilst a valid alternative) does not make use of.

Comment: @Peppermintology I didn't know about that package. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase added. Thanks for pointing me out.

Answer (score 0):

The other way around is just call the route name.

```
<form action="{{ route('your.route.name') }}">
   ...
</form>
```